# Mapbox-gl-js directions plugin returns directions only for the last call made in case of simultaneous calls

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to retrieve directions for multiple routes using mapbox-gl-js Directions API plugin (https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js).

The following code requests the directions and draws them on Map.

```
var mapBoxDrawDrivingPath = function(routeArray, day)
    {

        var colorArray = ['#4286f4' , '#7312bc' , '#11bc2e' , '#80bc11', '#bc2411'];
        //var stringDay = day.toString(16);
        var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5));

        var lineColor =  colorArray[rand] ; 


        console.log("Day : " + day + " " + lineColor);

        console.log(routeArray[0]);
        var MapBoxDir = new MapboxDirections({accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken });


        map.panTo(routeArray[0]);
        MapBoxDir.setOrigin(routeArray[0]);

        MapBoxDir.setDestination(routeArray[routeArray.length -1]);


        MapBoxDir.on('route', function(e) {
        //the following function is altered to return "lng,lat" instead of "lat,lng"
         var routeGeometry = polyLineDecode(e.route[0].geometry);

          map.addLayer(
                 {
                "id": "route"+day,
                "type": "line",
                "source": {
                    "type": "geojson",
                    "data": {
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "properties": {},
                        "geometry": {
                            "type": "LineString",
                                "coordinates": routeGeometry
                                //routeGeometry
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "layout": {
                        "line-join": "round",
                        "line-cap": "round"
                    },
                    "paint": {
                        "line-color": lineColor,
                        "line-width": 4
                    }
                });

        });







    }
```

The above function is called multiple times with different set of coordinates. Since the result of directions is a non-blocking behavior on callback, the function "mapBoxDrawDrivingPath" is called one after the other without waiting for result from previous call.

I assumed it would return respective directions for each enqueued call but  it returns the directions of the last inputs in all of its callback returns.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Just for clarity, the Mapbox Directions API (https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#introduction) is not part of Mapbox-GL-JS. They're separate APIs. Now, I don't quite understand the problem you're describing - can you put a runnable demo online? "It returns the directions of the last inputs" isn't clear to me.